# Angularjs table gride

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angulajs, I want to get filed values from database and need to place those values in table format using `ng-repeat` I have hot coded code..

Pls guide me how to use that ..

Code:

```
<tbody>
   <!-- ngRepeat: contact in contactList | orderBy:predicate:reverse | bsTableSkip:bsTablePagination.skipAt | limitTo:bsTablePagination.pageSize -->
   <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactList | orderBy:predicate:reverse | bsTableSkip:bsTablePagination.skipAt | limitTo:bsTablePagination.pageSize" class="ng-scope">
     <td class="ng-binding">FirstName 0</td>
     <td class="ng-binding">LastName 0</td>
     <td class="ng-binding">Jul 10, 2014</td>
     <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Show(contact)">Show</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Edit(contact)">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Remove(contact)">Remove</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- end ngRepeat: contact in contactList | orderBy:predicate:reverse | bsTableSkip:bsTablePagination.skipAt | limitTo:bsTablePagination.pageSize -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: I don't believe anyone can understand your question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to show us your JavaScript aswell. 
second, your td is not repeating you contactlist. 
You have to put {{contact."Whatever you need to get"}}.

If i misunderstood your question, lemme know.